# Pandas Year-Month format to timestamp

Tags: pandas, timestamp, time-series

I have dataframe with time index like this

```
2015-01
2015-02
2015-03
2015-04
2015-05
```

Now I would like to convert them to timestamps, like this

```
2015-01-31 00:00:00
2015-02-28 00:00:00
2015-03-31 00:00:00
2015-04-30 00:00:00
2015-05-31 00:00:00
```

How do I convert them? I tried something like this, but it requires days which I do not have.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
df.index = [dt.datetime(d.year, d.month) for d in df.index]
`TypeError`: Required argument 'day' (pos 3) not found
```

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try first convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_datetime.html) and then add [`MonthEnd()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects):

```
print df
         a
2015-01  1
2015-02  2
2015-03  2
2015-04  3
2015-05  4

print df.index
PeriodIndex(['2015-01', '2015-02', '2015-03', '2015-04', '2015-05'], dtype='int64', freq='M')

df.index = df.index.to_datetime()
print df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01', '2015-02-01', '2015-03-01', '2015-04-01',
               '2015-05-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')

df.index = df.index + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()
print df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-31', '2015-02-28', '2015-03-31', '2015-04-30',
               '2015-05-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')

print df
            a
2015-01-31  1
2015-02-28  2
2015-03-31  2
2015-04-30  3
2015-05-31  4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helps

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want the time to be 00:00:00?  That would be midnight, between the penultimate and last day of the month

```
months = pd.Series(['2015-01', '2015-02', '2015-03', '2015-04', '2015-05'])
>>> [pd.Period(m, 'M').end_time for m in months]

[Timestamp('2015-01-31 23:59:59.999999999'),
 Timestamp('2015-02-28 23:59:59.999999999'),
 Timestamp('2015-03-31 23:59:59.999999999'),
 Timestamp('2015-04-30 23:59:59.999999999'),
 Timestamp('2015-05-31 23:59:59.999999999')]
```

Comment: Hmm, I never thought about this, it might be better